# Is there a vectorized way to calculate the gradient in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, derivative

How does one calculate the (symbolic) gradient of a multivariate function in sympy?

Obviously I could calculate separately the derivative for each variable, but is there a vectorized operation that does this?

For example

```
m=sympy.Matrix(sympy.symbols('a b c d'))
```

Now for i=0..3 I can do:

```
sympy.diff(np.sum(m*m.T),m[i])
```

which will work, but I rather do something like:

```
sympy.diff(np.sum(m*m.T),m)
```

Which does not work ("AttributeError: ImmutableMatrix has no attribute _diff_wrt").

Comment: This doesn't work because it would expect to take the derivative with respect to `m` as a variable, which it does not know how to do. Just use a list comprehension over `m`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension over `m`:

```
[sympy.diff(sum(m*m.T), i) for i in m]
```

Also, don't use `np.sum` unless you are working with numeric values. The builtin `sum` is better.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an alternative to @asmeurer. I prefer this way because it returns a SymPy object instead of a Python list.

```
def gradient(scalar_function, variables):
    matrix_scalar_function = Matrix([scalar_function])
    return matrix_scalar_function.jacobian(variables)

mf = sum(m*m.T)
gradient(mf, m)
```